# withSortColumn sorting failed with 2 digits

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios6, nsmutablearray

In my application i have used the the following code to set the array value from core data,i want add the array value withSortColumn reference  @"companyNormalOrder". The @"companyNormalOrder" having 1 to 12 values,

```
  statuses = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Bet_Bonus class]) withSortColumn:@"companyNormalOrder" withSortDescending:FALSE withPredicate:nil];
```

after fetching, The statuses array sorted in the following format

```
1
11
12
2
3
4
```

But i want to sort in the order of

```
1
2                
3
4
```

What change  should i want to made in my code,Can any one please help me

Comment: Did my answer help? Please let me know if you need more information. - Otherwise please note that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the type of the companyNormalOrder attribute to *Integer* in the Core Data model inspector, not *String*.